# samba does get configuered

Tags: samba

with every installation or update I get this error message:

/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory

I don't how to solve this problem. Would be thankfull for help.

Comment: firstly, you could type _testparm_ in a terminal box and see result.

Comment: I had a look into the directories already: the file ist there but cannot be found by installation/configuration

Comment: running testparm, this w3as the outcome:

Comment: ok that was to long. but is it enough already to show something?

Comment: Testparm will show you samba problems, but I found it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1610361